# Microsoft Excel Finding Position Based on two column data?

Tags: excel

```
Fail Count  Total Number    Position
0   666 3
1   555 5
0   777 1
2   444 7
1   888 4
2   655 6
3   566 9
3   780 8
0   700 2
```

Position column is result that I need automatically by function (any combination of builtin function or custom function). Logic here is the minimum value of column (Fail count) and maximum value of column (Total Number) will first position. And minimum value of column (Fail count) and second maximum value of column (Total Number) will second position. It will continue till end data of column A and B.

Comment: Fail Count Total Number Position
0  666  3
1  555  5
0  777  1
2  444  7
1  888  4
2  655  6
3  566  9
3  780  8
0  700  2

Comment: Please post the output you mean to get.

Comment: @sancho.s    Position column is the output. I putted it manually but I need it by function.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply sorting you data: Order by `Fail Count` ascending and, if equal `Fail Count`, by `Total Number` descending?

With a formula this becomes an array formula with very bad performance.

[image]

Formula in `D2`downwards:

```
{=MATCH(B2*10^(MAX($A$2:$A$1000)-A2),LARGE($B$2:$B$1000*10^(MAX($A$2:$A$1000)-$A$2:$A$1000),ROW($A$2:$A$1000)-ROW($A$1)),0)}
```

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to finish.